# CMake reference custom target in child project

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, cmake

A custom target defined in a parent project isn't coming up in a child project.

Extract from parent project's CMakeLists.txt file:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(test sh <some script>.sh)
SUBDIRS(src)
```

Extract from child project's CMakeLists.txt file (which resides under `src/<child project name>/`:

```
ADD_DEPENDENCIES(${PROJECT_NAME} test)
```

If you need more information from any of the CMakeLists.txt files, I can supply it but I thought what's mentioned above is the most relevant.

This works for me in Visual studio (i.e, `test` shows up as a dependency in both `<parent>.vcproj` and `<child>.vcproj`) but not in Xcode. In Xcode, it shows up in `<parent>.xcodeproj` but not `<child>.xcodeproj`.

So my issue really is getting it to work properly for Xcode.

======================================

Edit 1 (based on Antonio's comment):

The child project's CMakeLists.txt file also contains:

```
SET (PROJECT_NAME MyApp)
...
PROJECT(${PROJECT_NAME})
...
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES (${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generated-by-test-sh.c PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)
ADD_EXECUTABLE (${PROJECT_NAME} ${GUI_TYPE} ${SRC} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generated-by-test-sh.c)
```

Everything is properly defined as it should be. Like I said, it all works fine in Visual Studio.

Also, adding `if (TARGET test)` in the child returns true, so I'm guessing the child is aware of the target defined in the parent....but Xcode won't add the dependency in the child project. Hence if you try to build, Xcode will complain saying that `generated-by-test-sh.c` could not be found.

Comment: Do you have an actual target (`add_library` or `add_executable`) named ${PROJECT_NAME}?

Comment: I believe the source of the problem is in the `sh <some script>.sh`: Can it be that the environment in your XCode is "broken" and therefore your script `sh <some script>.sh` doesn't run properly? (e.g. sh cannot be found?)

Comment: Possibly but don't think that's the issue. The issue is why doesn't `test` appear as a dependency (in the child xcodeproj) to begin with, as it does in the parent. Whether or not the target executes properly (due to sh not being found) is a separate issue. In VS, the dependency appears in the project and the script gets executed at build time, which I think is how it's supposed to happen.

Comment: Are you selecting the specific generator for Xcode? http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/manual/cmake-generators.7.html#ide-build-tool-generators

Comment: Yes, I specified Xcode (hence why I have xcodeproj files as per my original question) and (not that I think it's relevant) `/usr/bin/clang` and `/usr/bin/clang++` for the compilers.

Comment: Anyone? Or does someone want to submit an answer saying Xcode is broken? I will accept that.